# RavenDB query with Linq and enum

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

Given this document class:

```
public class Tea
{
   public String Id { get; set; }

   public String Name { get; set; }

   public TeaType Type { get; set; }

   public Double WaterTemp { get; set; }

   public Int32 SleepTime { get; set; }
}

public enum TeaType
{
    Black,
    Green,
    Yellow,
    Oolong
}
```

I store a new Tea with the following code:

```
using (var ds = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080/" }.Initialize())
using (var session = ds.OpenSession("RavenDBFirstSteps"))
{
    Tea tea = new Tea() { Name = "Earl Grey", Type = TeaType.Black, WaterTemp = 99d, SleepTime = 3 };
    session.Store(tea);
    session.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine(tea.Id);
}
```

The tea will be successfully saved, but when I try to query all black teas with linq, I am getting no results:

```
using (var ds = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080/" }.Initialize())
using (var session = ds.OpenSession("RavenDBFirstSteps"))
{
    var dbTeas = from teas in session.Query<Tea>()
                    where teas.Type == TeaType.Black
                    select teas;

    foreach (var dbTea in dbTeas)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dbTea.Id + ": " + dbTea.Name);
    }
}
```

I also tried to save the Enum as Integer with the following command:

```
ds.Conventions.SaveEnumsAsIntegers = true;
```

But, the result is the same. All works when I use the Name or the WaterTemp. Does RavenDB supports Enums in this way or I am totally wrong?

Comment: Shouldnt TeaType be an int?

Comment: @ColinPear From the C# point of view, the enum TeaType is internally an int.

Comment: I see. I keep getting confused by the name of that prop

Comment: @ColinPear thank you for you answer. It was not the solution but I started thinking about the name of the prop :-)

Comment: I believe you can still use Type if you like. You can do `public TeaType @Type {get; set;}`

Comment: @ColinPear You're right, but I am not a fan of the verbatim operator when it comes to reserved keywords. I recommend to use another name instead of the keyword.

Comment: @Kai from Ravens point of view, everything is json. Enums are serialized as strings by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed that I got the answer. It is always not recommended to use properties with a name like Type, which can be a reserved keyword.

I renamed Type and everything works, so the answer is:

```
public class Tea
{
   public String Id { get; set; }

   public String Name { get; set; }

   public TeaType TeaType { get; set; }

   public Double WaterTemp { get; set; }

   public Int32 SleepTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @MattJohnson oh, sorry, I copied the wrong code. Now, it's correct one.